# How to check the content of Koa's ctx.query?

Tags: node.js, koa

For a Koa-based API server, I want to check what parameters the URL query contains.

My setup looks as simple as this:

```js
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = new Koa()

const Router = require('koa-router')
router = new Router()

router.get('/', ctx => {
    console.log(ctx.query)
})

app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())

app.listen(3000)
```

It seems that `ctx.query` has a structure like an object but doesn't work as one.

Methods like `ctx.query.hasOwnProperty()` or `ctx.query.toString()` result in an error saying that it is not a function.

Though, `Object.keys(ctx.query)` gives an array of the keys—which is confusing to me because it apparently *is* an object and should have above methods.

What is `ctx.query` exactly? How can I make the failing methods from above working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctx.query` is the return from Node.js' [`querystring.parse()`](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options) method. From the documentation:

> The object returned by the querystring.parse() method does not
>   prototypically inherit from the JavaScript Object. This means that
>   typical Object methods such as obj.toString(), obj.hasOwnProperty(),
>   and others are not defined and will not work.

You can check Koa's [request implementation](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/23f7f545abfe1fb6499cd61cc8ff41fd86cef4a0/lib/request.js).